# Python boto3 how to parse role_arn from AWS_CONFIG_FILE?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have an AWS config file that my boto3 session has access to, via the AWS_CONFIG_FILE environment variable.
The config file looks like this: (multi-account environment)

```
[profile profile1]
credential_source Environment
region=us-east-whatever
role_arn=arn:aws:iam:<ACCOUNT NUMBER 1>:role/all-profiles-same-role-name
[profile profile2]
credential_source Environment
region=us-east-whatever
role_arn=arn:aws:iam:<ACCOUNT NUMBER 2>:role/all-profiles-same-role-name
[profile profileN]
credential_source Environment
region=us-east-whatever
role_arn=arn:aws:iam:<ACCOUNT NUMBER N>:role/all-profiles-same-role-name
```

In my Python code, I am trying to setup RefreshableCredentails (boto3 method) using somethign like this: (excluding full code because I think the issue is mainly about parsing the aws_config_file):

```
def __get_session_credentials(self):
   # hardcode one role_arn for now but need to variablize
   session_ttl=3000
   aws_role_arn="arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT NUM>:role/all-profiles-same-role-name
   ...
```

Can I somehow parse the "role_arn" from the config file on a per profile basis to make that function more extensible? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module from the standard library:

```py
import configparser

from pathlib import Path


def main():

    path_to_config = Path(Path.home(), ".aws", "config")
    parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
    parser.read(path_to_config)

    for profile in parser.sections():

        if "role_arn" in parser[profile]:
            print(
                "Found profile", profile, "with role_arn", parser[profile]["role_arn"]
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm not going to share the output here, though ;-)

Comment: Great - do check out @iuridiniz answer as well - usually, you can make boto3 assume a role and exchange the credentials automatically. The story is a bit different if you want to pass on the credentials to another tool, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem could be solved if you configure a new environment variable `AWS_PROFILE`

According to boto3 docs[[1]](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html):

> AWS_PROFILE
>
> The default profile to use, if any. If no value is specified, Boto3 attempts to search the shared credentials file and the config file for the default profile.

And aws-cli (just for reference) docs[[2]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html):

> AWS_PROFILE
>
> Specifies the name of the AWS CLI profile with the credentials and options to use. This can be the name of a profile stored in a credentials or config file, or the value default to use the default profile.
>
> If defined, this environment variable overrides the behavior of using the profile named [default] in the configuration file. You can override this environment variable by using the --profile command line parameter.

---

So, just set this environment variable to the `profileN`